# Restore Windows NT 3.51 boot loader without system diskettes

Tags: linux, windows, boot, mbr

I have an old Windows NT 3.51 machine and recently, Windows cannot boot. I do not have any system diskettes to try to restore the MBR from there and the machine doesn't have any usb ports. I only have a laptop (Dell Vostro) with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18. I can connect the hard disk with NT 3.51 to my lap with a USB adapter, so i was wondering if it is possible to restore NT from Windows 10 or Ubuntu using tools like dd (in linux, for example something like "dd if=io.sys of=/dev/sdb") or something similar in Windows 10. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if windows XP's bootloader can load winNT or not. Try `bootsect /nt52 drive: /mbr` on win10 to see

Comment: If you have an image for NT, you could do that. Slave the NT drive to your other computer and use any applicable imaging program. If you just need to repair the MBR, that could probably be done this way too. If you have to do a repair install or re-install, that will be more difficult and I'm not thinking of any way that can be accomplished besides getting the source files and a compatible drive system to do that with.